# Why output always get to 'catch'?

Tags: java, netbeans

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
// TODO add your handling code here:
// Mengambil nilai jLabel36Text dari jFrame1
jLabel36Text = landingViews.jLabel36Text;

```
// Mengatur nilai jLabel8 dengan jLabel36Text
jLabel18.setText(jLabel36Text);
jLabel19.setText(String.valueOf(jLabel32Text));

//memanggil menu
jLabel3.setText(jLabel10Text);
jLabel5.setText(jLabel12Text);
jLabel7.setText(jLabel11Text);
jLabel9.setText(jLabel13Text);

//memanggil jumlah
jLabel4.setText(""+hitungan);
jLabel6.setText(""+hitungan2);
jLabel8.setText(""+hitungan3);
jLabel10.setText(""+hitungan4);

//memanggil harga
jLabel11.setText(""+harga1);
jLabel12.setText(""+harga2);
jLabel13.setText(""+harga3);
jLabel14.setText(""+harga4);



try {
        String id = "";
        String namaMenu = this.jLabel10Text;
        double harga = this.harga1;
        int jumlah =this.hitungan;
        double subtotal = this.harga1;
        
        
        if (namaMenu.isEmpty()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data tidak boleh kosong");
            this.requestFocus();
        }
         else {
            cont.addMenu(id, namaMenu, harga, jumlah, subtotal);
            this.dispose();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Menu telah terinput");
            landingViews logView = new landingViews();
            logView.show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Register Gagal");
    }
```

i expecting this netbeans code button send the data on cont.addMenu(id, namaMenu, harga, jumlah, subtotal);
to myPHPAdmin. but it cant`your text`

Comment: Change `System.out.println("Register Gagal");` to `e.printStackTrace();` <- This will provide you with more useful information as to the reason for the exception (and it's actual source)